# Selenium Webdriver Unable to create new remote session on Firefox gecko driver

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium 2.53.1 and Mozilla 37.0. While executing script throws exception as below:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=Firefox, moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}}]
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
>   System info: host: 'JAYANT-PC', ip: '192.168.132.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

How can avoid this Error?

Answer (score 0):

Your gecko driver and selenium versions are possibly mismatched.  Please refer to this github thread:  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3630

Answer (score 0):

update your firefox and use selenium 3.3.1 and geckodriver 0.15.0,it will work